# clang support for fat-lto-objects

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, clang, lto

I have a project where I use `-flto=thin` for my main targets, but I don't want to apply LTO to my tests since it slows compilation down (full context: [lld runs LTO even if -fno-lto is passed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72190379)).

As it is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72249840/1214125), it is likely that if you compile with `lto` the object files will only contain the intermediate language and no binary code. Therefore the tests will always be linked with LTO

GCC has the `fat-lto-objects` option: *"Fat LTO objects are object files that contain both the intermediate language and the object code. This makes them usable for both LTO linking and normal linking."*

- Does clang have anything like that? It looks like that as for `clang++13` the `fat-lto-objects` option is just ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was supposed to be released in Clang 17, https://llvm.org/docs/FatLTO.html

https://www.phoronix.com/news/LLVM-Fat-LTO-Objects

Confusingly, this LLVM ticket mentions it only comes out in LLVM 18. https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/55431#issuecomment-1694769726